Why does my testIfPrime() function in C give me false positive primes?
I'm making a calculator that takes text based inputs for my intro to C programming class. This is our first assignment using functions. One of the possible functions my calculator needs to have is the ability to test primality. I could've looked up someone else's prime testing function, but I wanted to do this to make sure I learned. Well, I clearly messed up, because my function is now telling me that every odd number is prime, which is obviously wrong.
Note: I have the input for a function as a double, because I need the calculator to compute floats, so I just convert it in the prime testing function.
void testIfPrime(double lfNumber1) {
    
    int iNumber = 0;
    int iIterate;
    
    iNumber = (int)floor(lfNumber1);

    // Eliminating all the obvious nonprimes.
    if (iNumber == 0 || iNumber == 1 || (iNumber % 2 == 0))
        printf("\n%d is not a prime number.\n", iNumber);
    else {
        for (iIterate = 3; iIterate < iNumber; iIterate++) {
            if (iNumber % iIterate == 0) { 
                printf("\n%d is not a prime number.\n", iNumber);
                break;
            } //end if
            else {
                printf("\n%d is a prime number.\n", iNumber);
                break; 
            } //end else
        } //end for loop
    } //end if/else loop 
} //end testIfPrime def

I begin my function by labeling every obvious nonprime (0, 1, and every even). After that, I use else to enter a a for loop where I iterate and divide by my iterating variable. I think whats happening is the for loop modulo 2 on the odd numbers in the first iteration, modulo comes back != 0, so it assumes the the odd number is prime and doesnt continue further.
Not sure how I can fix this, maybe a while loop? just adding more loops doesn't seem like it well help. I ran it through a for loop to test every  number from 1-100, and the odd prime, even non-prime pattern continued.
Thank you for the help!

you can't tell that a number is prime until you go all the way through the loop and don't find any factors. You're saying it's prime whenever you find some number that isn't a factor.

Notice that you have break in both branches of your if statement. So the loop never repeats, all you're checking is whether 3 is a factor.

2 is prime; the only "even" prime number...

Your code won't say that all odd numbers are prime. It will say that all odd numbers except multiples of 3 are prime.

Note that you should not search up to N-1. A better test is x <= N / x; it
avoids overflow and uses integer division.
If N is composite, one factor is not larger than √N and the other
is not smaller than √N).
After checking for 'divisible by 2', you can check only the odd
numbers.
If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger
primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer K starting at K equal to 1.
Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when N is just in
the thousands, let alone much bigger.
Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3.

Look up "Sieve of Eratosthenes". That's the simplest of the good prime testing methods.  (Also, don't do those "//end if/else loop" comments; they just clutter your code.)

Off-topic, but in C language, naming variables in Hungarian notation is generally discouraged.

The first step when debugging should always be to step through the code in a debugger. Especially when learning this will help you build intuition and understand your code.
One observation: It's weird checking if a double is prime. Not all doubles can be represented as integers. iNumber = (int)floor(lfNumber1); is also redundant, you can just do iNumber = (int)lfNumber1;. You should also take care with negative numbers.
Another observation: 2 is prime but you incorrectly report it as non-prime.
The most important bug in your code though is that you print break in both cases in the inner if-else. No matter what, you only ever check iNumber % iIterate == 0 and decide prime/composite based on that. You need to check a lot more numbers before deciding it's composite.

What debugger do you  recommend? I'm currently using Embarcadero Dev-C  for my editor and compiler.
I have to convert from double to int because the calculator accepts double inputs. I have a note in the code saying only use an int for the prime test, but I just have it convert to int so it doesnt cause an error if someone inputs a float.

Thanks for the advice on the other parts. I'll figure out how to check all the other numbers and take that break out.

If you're on windows then visual studio community edition is the easiest to setup and get started with.

Wrong to truncate
iNumber = (int)floor(lfNumber1); is a bad first step.  Values with a fraction are not prime.  Better to look for a fraction first.
Loss of range
(int)floor(lfNumber1); is undefined behavior (UB) for value much outside the int range.
Consider a wider type like unsigned long long that generally encodes all double with a continuous whole number value.  E.g. [0 ... 2^53].
Fails for negatives
iNumber == 0 || iNumber == 1 || (iNumber % 2 == 0) does not fail negatives and incorrectly says 2 is not a prime.
Better as:
if (iNumber < 3 || (iNumber % 2 == 0)) {
  printf("\n%d is %s prime number.\n", iNumber, (iNumber == 2) ? "": "not");
}

Missing return
for (iIterate = 3; iIterate < iNumber; iIterate++) { fails to print anything when iNumber == 3.
Wrong else
else { printf("\n%d is a prime number.\n", iNumber); is  amiss.  Just because one modulo test failed, the number is not certainly a prime.  Continue iterating instead.
Test up to n times is grossly inefficient
Testing up to the square root of n is enough.  Avoid divisor*divisor <= unumber in integer math as that, in general, overflows for large primes.

Alternate (untested) code:
// Return true is a prime.
bool testIfPrime(double number) {
  // fail NANs, Infinity and negatives. 
  if (!isfinite(number) || number < 0) {
    return false;
  }

  // If number more than precision, than it is an even number, not prime.
  if (number >= (ULLONG_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0) {
    return false;
  }

  // Look for a fraction.  
  double ipart;
  if (modf(number, &ipart)) {
    return false;
  }

  // Move to integer math.
  unsigned long long unumber = (unsigned long long) number;

  // Reject most even numbers.
  if (unumber%2 == 0) {
    return unumber == 2;
  } 

  // Test up to the sqrt unumber;
  for (unsigned long divisor = 3; divisor <= unumber/divisor; divisor += 2) {
    if (unumber%divisor == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return unumber > 1;
}




To answer your question and based on what you already have. The problem is in your for-loop where you need complete the whole iterations first to conclude if it is a prime or not. Also, as other pointed out, your iIterator should increment by 2. Anyway, I think the code below should answer your question:
void testIfPrime(double lfNumber1) {
    
    int iNumber = 0;
    
    iNumber = (int)floor(lfNumber1);

    // Eliminating all the obvious nonprimes.
    if (iNumber == 2)
        printf("\n%d is a prime number.\n", iNumber);
    else if (iNumber == 0 || iNumber == 1 || (iNumber % 2 == 0))
        printf("\n%d is not a prime number.\n", iNumber);
    else {
        bool is_prime = true;
        for (int iIterate = 3; iIterate<=iNumber/iIterate; iIterate+=2) {
            if (iNumber % iIterate == 0) { 
                is_prime = false;
                break;
            } //end if
        } //end for loop
        if (!is_prime)
            printf("\n%d is not a prime number.\n", iNumber);
        else
            printf("\n%d is a prime number.\n", iNumber);
    } //end if/else loop 
} //end testIfPrime def


This does fix some issues with OP original code.  Yet this errantly reports testIfPrime(-1) and testIfPrime(2.5) as primes.  It has undefined behavior with large lfNumber1 such as testIfPrime(2.0*INT_MAX).

Read OP’s “I ran it through a for loop to test every number from 1-100, and the odd prime, even non-prime pattern continued.” - that’s what he was wondering.
